# Regex not matching in Go

Tags: regex, go, regex-alternation

I have a regex that is not matching in Go.

However in a regex playground it's matching fine: https://regex101.com/r/VNDXcQ/2.

It's matching JS comments.

Here is the code:

```golang
comment := "// fallback response. For more information contact support"
re := regexp.MustCompile(`/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|([^\\:]|^)\/\/.*$/gm`)
matches := re.MatchString(comment)
fmt.Println(matches) // false
```

Why could that be?

Comment: Who is submitting a close-vote with the reason as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"? What exactly in the example code provided in the question is not reproducible? The specified behavior is 100% reproducible. Here is the Go playground for it: https://play.golang.org/p/muUxpBOmOQV. It produces the output `false` exactly as mentioned in this question. Really, who is it that is going around close-voting most Go questions with this fake reason? Why are they doing this?

Comment: @LoneLearner: Totally agree with your point. From the many tags I follow, only here do I notice, more than decent questions with a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) getting downvoted and voted to close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two major issues:

- You are using a regex literal as a string regex pattern. It means, you need to remove the first and last `/` and "move" `m` flag to the pattern by converting it into a `(?m)` inline modifier
- You are only match the first occurrence with `MatchString` (since flags cannot be passed along with the regex pattern and `g` flag "is not supported"). You need to use [`FindAllString`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString) to get all matches.

You can fix that with

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|([^\\:]|^)//.*`)
matches := re.FindAllString(comment, -1)
```

Note `/` is not a special character and thus needs no escaping.

See [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pz-xZ1dJVLf).